# Custom scrollView when Scroll, move header view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have an question, like this photo
[User Profile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRhMc.jpg)

In Apple document, they say not add UITableView to UIScrollView, but now i needs to do this..? is someone have an good idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Listen to what Apple's documentation says. Don't add a UITableView to a UIScrollView. A UITableView is already a subclass of UIScrollView. If you need alternative approaches to accomplishing your needs, please elaborate on your reasoning.

Comment: you can simply add the segmented control as section header so that when you scroll the table view it will comes to top and remain there and reduce the height of the blur image to 0. So that it will looks as you expected

Comment: Hi, Tyson Vignesh, yes, you are right, that is i need

Comment: @JeremyHerrero i want to make an profile page like twitter's profile page..

Comment: @ilyi1116 I'm facing the same problem. Have you come up with any solution? Please help me.

Comment: @Manigandasaravanan i had use UITableView tableHeaderView with func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) { ....

Comment: @ilyi1116 Can you please share your code. I'm trying to solve this issue for around 1 week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know any swift custom library , but conceptually I think you can do it with a floating header view. I know 2 project in obectiveC you can bridge in your swift project:

- [DYFloatingHeaderView](https://github.com/dyang/DYFloatingHeaderView)
- [IBScrollViewFloatingHeader](https://github.com/ivanbruel/IBScrollViewFloatingHeader)

Both project, after you add this custom header view in your table, customize the scroll delegate methods, and you can override these methods for your personal pourpose.

Comment: Thanks for your share ^^

Answer (score 2):

The problem is kind of complex. There are different ways to solve that and none of them is easy.

You can add a table view inside a scrollview (nested techniques), but if you try to scroll it won't feel natural. To improve that user experience  you need to implement scrollview delegate methods and apply some inner logic. All this kind of techniques are explained in two wwdc 2013-14 videos [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/217/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/235/), but I strongly suggest you to watch also earlier sessions of 2011-12 to unleash the power of scrollviews.

The best way is to implement a `UICollectionView` with a custom layout, this is also explained in [Advanced collection view user interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/232/) from wwdc 2014, in these session Apple explain how they developed AppStore application that contains a floating header.
Another solution is search on github, you can find [CSSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout) or similar solutions.

The last one can be applied if you just need to add a header to a scrollview (without nesting another scrollview) just using auto layout.

Comment: Thank you give me an idea, i will try to use CSSStickyHeaderFlowLayout for layout my profile  view

Answer (score 1):

The layout image which you have attached, its kind of paralax control.

I had some kind of layout earlier and configured easily with.

https://github.com/Vinodh-G/ParallaxTableViewHeader

```
 let headerView : ParallaxHeaderView = ParallaxHeaderView.parallaxHeaderViewWithImage(UIImage(named: ""), forSize: CGSizeMake(self.tableview.frame.size.height, headerHeight)) as! ParallaxHeaderView

 self.tableview.tableHeaderView = headerView


func  scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let header: ParallaxHeaderView = self.tabkeview.tableHeaderView as! ParallaxHeaderView
    header.layoutHeaderViewForScrollViewOffset(scrollView.contentOffset)

    self.tableview.tableHeaderView = header



}
```

Comment: thanks for your share, this make me many idea ^^, and i will try this with Top [Tyson Vignesh] says: put me segmentedControl in the UITableView Section Header